# pandas np where multiple logical codition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, logical-operators

I using python 3+ with jupyter notebook and pandas.

I am trying to create a new column based on two existing conditions. I am aware that I could use conditions, values, select except that I have mutilple columns, so i thought the method I am using would be quicker. Evidently not. Any help would be appreciated.

```
dfTest['Custodian_Non-Algo'] = np.where(np.logical_and(dfTest['BuyClientIdentity'] == 3 ,dfTest['BuyAlgoIndicator'] == 1), 2, 0)
```

While this does not throw any errors, it is not calculating the column as expected.

Could anyone suggest a solution please?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your DataFrame and a desired output?

Comment: `dfTest['Custodian_Non-Algo'] = np.where((dfTest['BuyClientIdentity'] == 3)& (dfTest['BuyAlgoIndicator'] == 1), 2, 0)
`

Comment: Hi all, thanks for revieiwng and answering this. The values in my columns were strings, and as such, the logic was correct, it just wasnt recognising a string as an int. Apologies, new to python, learnt my lesson the hard way there, will check that in the future.